# Issue with B2C edit profile custom policy on return to main site

Tags: c#, .net, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a .Net 4.6.2 web application that is being set up to use AAD B2C. It has an OwinStartup class that has the following:

```
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                MetadataAddress = String.Format($"{b2cAadInstance}", b2cTenantName,"v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=", b2cSignInPolicy,""),
                ClientId = b2cClientId,
                RedirectUri = b2cRedirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = b2cRedirectUri,
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "cookie",
                // authorize scope
                Scope = "openid offline_access",
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
                UseTokenLifetime = false,
                RedeemCode = true,
                SaveTokens = true,
                ResponseType = "code",
                ResponseMode = "query",
                // Specify the callbacks for each type of notifications
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                }

            });
```

This all works fine when signing in. The user is authenticated and redirected to the main site. However, the code is set up to send them back to a custom policy for editing their profile. It does that in OnRedirectToIdentityProvider with this code:

```
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy) && !policy.Equals(b2cSignInPolicy, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress.ToLower().Replace(b2cSignInPolicy.ToLower(), policy.ToLower());
            }
```

This works to send the user to the custom edit profile policy. However, the problem is when they finish editing their profile and B2C returns them to the site. The `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` method is called, but immediately after that, `OnAuthenticationFailed` is also called and B2C is providing the following error message:

> OpenIdConnectMessage.Error was not null, indicating an error. Error: 'invalid_grant'. Error_Description (may be empty): 'AADB2C90088: The provided grant has not been issued for this endpoint. Actual Value : B2C_1A_SignIn and Expected Value : B2C_1A_ProfileEdit

`B2C_1A_ProfileEdit` is what is passed in for `policy` in the above code, which is what sends the user to the profile edit screens.

I have seen a couple of examples of code that appear like they should handle this situation, but they are all in .Net Core, which unfortunately doesn't work with how 4.6.2 works with B2C.

Comment: You might also need to update the `MetadataAddress` endpoint as B2C includes the policy name in the endpoints returned in the response.

Comment: @AquilaSands Thanks, I tried that, but unfortunately that didn't change anything. I'll continue to keep looking.

Comment: @CharlesBoyung did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: @Rob I honestly can't remember if we fixed it or what happened - and I'm not working with that client anymore, so I don't really even have a way to go back and check - sorry.